# How to disable zero-padding leniency in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I'm using `SimpleDateFormat` with pattern `"MM"` and try to parse `"0012"`.

Even with leniency disabled the formatter will successfully parse this to december. I'd like it to throw an exception, this is no 2-digit-month. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

**Code**

Example code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM");
df.setLenient( false);
System.out.println( df.parse( "0012"));
```

Output:

> Tue Dec 01 00:00:00 CET 1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move on and use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd")` will parse `00` as the month and then object because it isn’t followed by a hyphen, `-` (that is, before even checking to see that 00 isn’t a valid month number).

I think you should want to use `java.time` anyway. The `SimpleDateFormat` class you’re using is not only outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome.

**Link:** [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't just move on, solving that problem with SimpleDateFormat is less risky than changing the api and being forced to do lots of regression tests.

Comment: You don’t have to migrate your code base and regression test everything. You may use `java.time` in just the lines you are writing now. If you need to get an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` object from parsing, convert through the `Instant` class, for example `Date.from(myParsedOffsetDateTime.toInstant())`.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's either that or nothing. Just dug into the Java code itself. The BigDecimal formatter that is used in SimpleDateFormat has this comment of code `// Ignore leading zeros in integer part of number.` followed by respective code. So there's no solution other than writing the formatter yourself or use your suggestion. I rather use yours. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution for this problem, but here it goes. I suggest checking if the value introduced by the user is bigger than 2 digits (I supposed the input is an String) inside of an exception handler and creating an exception if it does:

```
try{

    if(str.length() > 2){

        int crash = (1/0);

    }

}catch (ArithmeticException e){

    System.out.println("You've introduced a month format larger than MM");

    //introduce the code you'll like to be executed when the Exception is 
    //fired.

}
```

I understand this is not the best way to solve this issue. However, it works. If someone has any better idea just tell me and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but that's more like a hack. I need a proper solution. In the end flexible parsing should be possible. Quick Example: Using list of patterns "MM" and "HHmm" and iterating through all parsing 0012 until successful, the text 0012 should translate to time 00:12 instead of month 12. I can't change the order, unfortunately, other pattern-combinations have similar problems.

Comment: @Roland Maybe using an if/else statement for comparing the length of the String introduced by the user to determine whether they are a month or not? Or you have to compulsory use patterns?

Comment: I have to use patterns, any combination of them. So I'm stuck with strict checks. I guess the problem might be the numberformat and I have to write a custom formatter. Gonna dive into the Java source itself. But thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `0012` is month and year with 2 digits each, you can use `MMyy` as pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyy");
df.setLenient(false);
System.out.println(df.parse("0012"));
```

This will throw the following exception,

> ```
> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "0012"
> ```